# Windows servers on same gigabit lan switch, what might cause Windows 2008 R2 to have 50% longer ping times than Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows, networking, performance, ping

After installing a brand new HP Proliant DL380e Gen8 running SBS 2011 (Windows 2008 R2 X64) I noticed a difference in response to `ping` requests on the wired ethernet local LAN, even before the migration from the old SBS 2003 was completed.

The ping round-trip time (min/avg/max/stddev) differences for 31 packets:

1. 0.319/0.437/0.814/0.095 ms (slowest!)
2. 0.250/0.380/0.502/0.061 ms
3. 0.210/0.293/0.368/0.040 ms

The differences (in the same order as the list above):

1. HP DL380e Gen8, SBS 2011, 8GB low voltage RAM, no load
2. Supermicro SCS216, SBS 2003, 4GB RAM, highest load
3. HP DL160 Gen5, Server 2003, 8GB, low load

Regression:

1. All servers are connected to the same 3Com 2816 baseline gigabit switch
2. All servers have a 1 gigabit link speed
3. All servers have a CAT5e patch cable between 1 and 2 meters in length
4. DL380e Intel E1R firmware has been updated to version 4.0.0.10 [11 Sep 2013]
5. DL380e Intel E1R driver is version 12.7.28.0 (B) [10 Sep 2013]

What might cause the new Windows 2008 R2 server (handling the lowest load) to have the highest (slow) ping times?

Comment: Drivers? Are they on the latest avalible?

Comment: Those differences are very small... Could be firewall, AV software, etc?

Comment: @xeon Min. is 52% slower, Avg. is 49% slower, Maximum packet round-trip  takes 2.2 times longer, I don't call this very small. There is not yet any firewall neither antivirus software installed on the new SBS 2011/Windows 2008 R2 installation.